# Please explain the continue statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, continue

Please can anyone explain the continue statement, I have been trying my best to break it down to my understanding but all efforts have been futile. Here is a sample program I found in the python docs and I can't understand it.

```
for num in range(2, 10):
    if num % 2 == 0:
        print("Found an even number", num)
        continue
    else:
        print("Found a number", num)
```

Comment: it just causes the code to continue with the next iteration of the loop. not really required in your example.

Comment: Did you check the Python docs? You'll find in good detail what `continue` does

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `continue` statement causes Python to skip the rest of the current iteration of the loop, and jump to the beginning of the next iteration.

See [this documentation page](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) for Python 3. The original example on that page is:

```
>>> for num in range(2, 10):
...     if num % 2 == 0:
...         print("Found an even number", num)
...         continue
...     print("Found a number", num)

Found an even number 2
Found a number 3
Found an even number 4
Found a number 5
Found an even number 6
Found a number 7
Found an even number 8
Found a number 9
```

When `continue` is encountered, the `print` at the end of the loop is skipped, and execution goes to the `for` again to get the next iteration. Note how for even numbers, "Found an even number" is printed, but "Found a number" is *not* printed. This is because the `continue` skipped the rest of the loop body.

---

Your modification to the sample - inserting the `else` - makes the `continue` obsolete, because the `print("Found a number", num)` wouldn't be executed anyway (it sits in an `else`) branch.

This way you've discovered that `continue` (and also `break`) are often an alternative control flow mechanism to `if...else`. Which to use depends on the situation and style preferences.

Comment: And after jumping to the next iteration, does it make python return back to the skipped iteration

Comment: @Faruq: No. For example in case of 2, `continue` is invoked and jumps to the next iteration which is 3 (next value yielded by `range`). It won't ever get back to 2 again.

Comment: oh, i think i get it now. Sorry for the questions, i'm just 13

Comment: @Faruq: that's OK. I suppose Python doesn't spend too much explaining `continue` because it's very familiar from C. It makes sense to play with simple examples until the idea sinks. Another idea is to follow the execution of this loop in the debugger (`pdb`)